# Best way to compress a DateTime into a string?

Tags: c#, datetime, compression

I'm storing a `DateTime` value into a string for storing in a database, along with other data. *I'm aware this is not the most optimal way to store a `DateTime`*. Having said that, I want to store it while occupying as few characters as possible.

Right now I'm storing it in the `yyyyMMddHHmm` format, occupying 12 characters. I don't care about the seconds. Is it possible to further reduce the number of characters to store this element without losing data?

Comment: possible? yes. with lots of effort: recommendable: ***absolutely not***, except for experimentation and education. but the main question is: if you _know_ that storing datetimes as string is a stupid idea - ***why*** do you want to do it anyway? (plus: the best way for storing a datetime, besides datetime, would be to save a numeric unix-timestamp)

Comment: You could do some bit packing (only need 5 bits to store the hour, for example), and then probably base64-encode it again for safe storage (which collation?). But why? What will shaving off a few bytes gain, knowing that you'll have to do the calculation over and over again (both for reading and writing), and won't be able to do any math on the dates (not that that's trivial using strings), and you can't interpret the data easily by querying the database?

Comment: I'm saving the DateTime only for visualization in a game log (kind of like a chat with all the moves made in a turn-based game). This is only for visualization and for nothing else, so I don't care about second-accuracy. And yes, saving a few bytes won't probably impact anything at all to the bandwidth, but I was also interested in this from an experimental point of view. Probably not fundamental, and could be done in a smarter way, but something I was interested in anyways.

Comment: Store a `DateTime`.  No compression required.  No conversion needed. Much simpler. Definitely smarter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **six** characters with a very simple method:

```cs
string logTime = "202103011927";

char[] code = new char[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    code[i] = (char)(32 + int.Parse(logTime.Substring(2 + 2 * i, 2)));
}
string display = new string(code);
Console.WriteLine(display);

char[] chars = display.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder decode = new StringBuilder("20");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    decode.Append(Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToByte(chars[i]) - 32)).ToString("00"));
}
Console.WriteLine(decode.ToString());

// 5#!3;
// 202103011927
```

Comment: That's a creative approach that would appear to stay within printable, ASCII-compatible characters.

Comment: Beware, this algorithm isn't suitable for representing milliseconds because character pair 94 through 99 will overflow. This also means that come 2094 we're probably going to have the Y2K and 2038 bugs all over again...

Comment: @IanKemp: Check it out, please, before posting comments. Where/why do 2038 and 2094 come into play? This simple method will work flawlessly until 209912315959; and seconds, thus of course also milliseconds, are - and were requested to be - ignored.

Comment: @Gustav I'm fully aware of the constraints, but I'm also aware that people (like me) who are looking to store a date-time value are also likely going to want to store milliseconds too, and might try to use your algorithm to do this - which won't work. I'm also aware that this algorithm may end up being used in part of a system that isn't ever modified, in which case it will become a problem in 2094. I don't think it's unfair or unreasonable to point out these limitations.

Comment: @IanKemp: Well, nowhere has a universal method been requested, neither was my answer claimed to be. It is a direct answer to a specific and uncommon question. If you for any answer should list all those scenarios where it would not work as intended, we would never get a night's sleep. The hard limit for this simple method is 2099 where we, anyway, most likely will have computer systems very different from those of today.